# Jpa repository giving exception when use custom query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I am using a repository interface which extends JpaRepository. I am using the following query and it gives a jdbc exception executing SQL.

My repository:

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {

    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM bookbelongto WHERE userid = ?1 AND bookid = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    public void removeBookFromListR(Long userid, Long bookid);


    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO bookbelongto(userid, bookid) VALUES(:pId, :bId)", nativeQuery = true)
    public int saveBookToPersonR(@Param("pId") Long pId, @Param("bId") Long bId);
}
```

These queries are supposed to work on a relationship table.

Comment: Show the full stack trace of the exception - add it to the question as formatted text.

Comment: Take a look at `?1` and `?2`. Those look odd. I expect just `?` as the placeholders.